# Custom Jenkins Plugin - how can I override values loaded from older versions of the plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm develping custom Jenkins plugin.

As part of the development I had to make some changes to the classes and fields of my custom build step.

As a result, each client that updates the plugin has to re-enter the configuration of some of the fields.

I wonder if there is a way to load the old values and map them to the new fields?

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,
Nadv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Hint on retaining backward compatibility](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hint+on+retaining+backward+compatibility) in the Jenkins wiki. It covers all relevant cases, e.g. adding/removing/renaming fields.

Comment: Do you have any tips regarding the best approach to support downgrade of a plugin?